# Woocommerce Paypal Pro Checkout

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently testing a website made with Woocommerce and Paypal Pro Entension. I'm working with a sandbox bussiness pro account.

Right before the checkout, i got this warning saying : 
Pay with your credit card via PayPal Website Payments Pro. TEST/SANDBOX MODE ENABLED. In test mode, you can use the card number 4007000000027 with any CVC and a valid expiration date.

Since I'm in test mode, I am using the given credit card number but when I checkout, it loads...indefinitely. And the transaction never go threw.

Since I dont get any error message, I'm having trouble to find out what causes the problem and theres no "fake money" deposit made in my Paypal Sandbox Bussiness pro account.

Can you help me?
Thanks you.

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors in the browser's deverloper console?

Comment: I would recommend using a different test number than that.  Google "test credit card numbers" and you'll find a generator that can give you random test cards to use.  They'll work just fine in the PayPal sandbox.  That number you're showing has been used so much in the sandbox that it often fails.

Comment: Hi, I tried using different card numbers found by google search - None of them worked. Still loading indefinitely. No error message. Also tried checking out with a Sandbox personal account. Same thing.

@helgatheviking : where could I see those error? Since it loads indefinitely, I have no hint of the cause. Also, i'm supposed to have a folder in woocommerce/logs/paypal-pro.txt. 

When you says browser's developper console, means firebug?

I went on my server and the folder doesnt exist. Where could I see those Javascript errors?

Comment: Yes Firebug (or equivalent). In Firebug there is a "console" tab. Try reloading your page and see what pops up there. PayPal is notoriously difficult to test with.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for the info. I get this error when looking into the console tab : 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of null. 

Any idea?

Comment: Here is an image of the exact error message : http://agencesecrete.com/meme/error-js.jpg

Comment: Could you post the answer in case someone else has the same problem?

Comment: Yes! Following the error message 'Uncaught TypeError'. I found on Github a post with the same problem suggesting to invert two lines of code in checkout.js and checkout.min.js

The problem was cause by the order of execution, the page was reloading before taking the customer's information.

LINK TO POST
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/5332